# Eclipse NewSearchUI hide progress dialog while running a search query

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I used the `NewSearchUI.runSearchInBackground(query)` to run a search query. This causes a Progress dialog to pop up, where user have the button "Run in Background". The `Job.setUser()` is set to `true` for the Job in `InternalSaerchUI.runSearchInBackgound`, which is why the dialog always pops up.

However I would like to hide the dialog from the beginning, so that the user can look at the search results quickly, without having to minimize the progress dialog. Is there a way to achieve that? Aside from the setting it in the preferences options and checking the run always in background checkbox.

References:
[Search example](http://codeandme.blogspot.de/2015/07/a-custom-search-provider.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a progress dialog shows up or not isn't really meant to be controlled by the initiator of a user job.

As you already pointed out, the workspace-wide preference controls if a progress dialog is shown or not.

Apart from disabling the progress dialog in general, there is no way that I know of to prevent the progress dialog from appearing.

If you think it is generally useful to hide the progress dialog for search jobs, you may want to file an enhancement request here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform

Comment: If I do a file search in a normal eclipse, no search dialog appears as the search view gets populated. Wonder why the behaviour of the NewSearchUI is not the same, or is it that they are using some different implementation.

Comment: @2c00L If I read the Text Search code correctly the initial search job just schedules a number of other jobs which actually do the search - so the first job finishes quickly before the progress dialog appears.

Comment: There is a short delay before a progress dialog is shown. If the job finishes before that, no dialog is shown.

Comment: @greg-449 Aha! So there is that trick. I used the same and just scheduled another background job to update the Search View, now the dialog does not appear while the view is updated. Thanks guys.